# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I am getting this error:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

This is my logcat log:

```
11-11 22:47:28.930: D/my(25127): method equals POST is working
11-11 22:47:28.930: D/my(25127): HTTp client is working
11-11 22:47:28.930: D/my(25127): HTTp post is working
11-11 22:47:28.930: D/my(25127): url encoded
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): HTTp response is working
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): HTTp entity is working
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): getcontent is working
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): buffer reader crated
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): string buffer object crated
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): line appended
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): inputstram closed
11-11 22:47:29.070: D/my(25127): string buffer to string conversion
11-11 22:47:29.070: E/JSON Parser(25127): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value prepared of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Error can be in server side script.

The pure JSON response is:

```
{"success":1,"message":"account successfully created."}
```

I have tested it in my browser.

Comment: Use at least `e.printStacktrace` or something else to look at the exact stacktrace of the error, which contains the number of the problematic line.

Comment: so much logs ... but you forgot to log http response code and response itself ...

Comment: what is response share it.

Comment: Quite simply, your server is returning HTML and not a pure JSON string.

Comment: the response you have share is the value of json from which you have created the jObj object print this value.

Comment: ...not the one from browser

Comment: @piyush so which response you are talking about? I can entry in db, but the android client is not identified because the JSON response with values is not parsed.

Comment: because it is not json, xyz why you are discussing with facts?

Comment: @Selvin so, where do I see the pure JSON response?

Comment: json = sb.toString(); this thing since its an string you can print it in log we want this response.

Comment: @piyush where do I see the pure JSON response

Comment: just print this and tell us json = sb.toString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the question myself.

In backend PHP file, I used `echo` statements, which also outputted as response. So, the  json String contained a html tags and/or lines and so, it couldn't be parsed.

Remove all `echo` statements or relative statements in your backend file. It will work. Thanks.

Comment: Thats what we were saying json = sb.toString();  this is not json.

Comment: it's not working ..even after removing echo

Comment: So what do you used to send response back instead of echo

Answer (score 3):

You json String contains a `<br />` tag so it can't be parsed.

Try you url in a browser and check that the result is pure json.

Comment: No, let me edit the question.

Comment: yes... it is written in the exception ... similar questions were asked many times here

Comment: What does the url passed to `makeHttpRequest` give in a browser ?

Comment: @ToYonos whatever the url has passed, the code is working upto httpPost.

Comment: no, it is not working... log json string before parsing ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to json object in post execute method.

Comment: this is not a relevant answer