# How to send data with JSONObjectRequest in Volley and I'm getting error Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley

This is `JsonObjectRequest` and I am getting the error. Help me out......

```
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
jsonParams.put("email",email.getText().toString());

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, new JSONObject(jsonParams), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                name.setText(response.getString("Name"));
                mobile.setText(response.getString("Mobile"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   error.printStackTrace();
               }
    }){
       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError{
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
       }
};

MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: the problem is on your `PHP` file add that here

Comment: whenever you get <BR error, that means the problem is in php side, not android. note it.

Comment: Refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/26871560/6452886 The problem might be from your backend PHP.

Comment: Make `StringRequest` intead of `JsonObjectRequest` because your response come in string not in JSONObject.

Comment: <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require "init.php";
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$email = $obj->{'email'}; 
$sql_getID="select * from user_registration where email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_getID);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) 
{  
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode(array("Name"=>$row["name"],"Email"=>$row["email"],"Mobile"=>$row["mobile"]));
} 
?>

Comment: @W4R10CK <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require "init.php";
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$email = $obj->{'email'}; 
$sql_getID="select * from user_registration where email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_getID);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) 
{  
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode(array("Name"=>$row["name"],"Email"=>$row["email"],"Mobile"=>$row["mobile"]));
} 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try using volley **StringRequest**, it seems, server is sending you Strings instead of JsonOBJECTS. If JsonObject is what you need, you must do some changes on the server side. If not try this:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Addresses.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("Response", jsonObject .toString());
                    name.setText(jsonObject .getString("Name"));
                    mobile.setText(jsonObject .getString("Mobile"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };

queue.add(request);
```

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, thank you for pointing out the mistake, I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your solution if your server receives values in json form.

```
JSONObject jsonobject= new JSONObject();
jsonobject.put("email",email.getText().toString());



    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, jsonobject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                            name.setText(response.getString("Name"));
                            mobile.setText(response.getString("Mobile"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```